"Navigation Stack Overflow and UI Glitch When Toggling Between Signin and Signup Pages in Expo Router Without Using Replace
Problem Description
I have the following navigation setup in my Expo Router project,
Main Layout:
 <Stack>
  <Stack.Screen name='(admin)' options={{ headerShown: false }} />
  <Stack.Screen name='(user)' options={{ headerShown: false }} />
  <Stack.Screen name='(auth)' options={{ headerShown: false }} />
  <Stack.Screen name='cart' options={{ presentation: 'modal' }} />
 </Stack>

Main Screen (index.tsx)
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", padding: 10 }}>
  <Link href="/(user)" asChild>
    <Button text="User" />
  </Link>
  <Link href="/(admin)" asChild>
    <Button text="Admin" />
  </Link>
  <Link href="/signin" asChild>
    <Button text="Sign in" />
  </Link>
</View>

Signin:
<Link href="/signup" style={styles.signup}>
  Create account
</Link>

SignUp:
<Link href="/signin" style={styles.signup}>
  login
</Link>

Current behaviour:

From the main screen (index.tsx), I navigate to signin using the "Sign in" button.
On the signin page, I navigate to signup by clicking "Create account."
If I repeatedly navigate between signin and signup (e.g., signin → signup → signin → signup), each navigation adds a new screen to the stack, at first header disappears, and then whole app goes gray(default android background color)

video for clarification
Expected Behavior:
seamlessly switch the pages.
the only solution that i've come up with is to add replace on the Link, but it causes the back button to redirect to main screen, instead of one before. example : Main -> signin -> signup -> back(causes to go back to Main, instead of signin)
